# how to append node from xml document to existing xml document

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have list of tournaments in my a.xml:

```
<tournaments>

    <tournament>
        <name>a</name>
    </tournament>

    <tournament>
        <name>b</name>
    </tournament>

    <tournament>
        <name>c</name>
    </tournament>

</tournaments>
```

ad then I have one tournament in b.xml

```
<tournament>
    <name>d</name>
</tournament>
```

How I can apend document b.xml to a.xml into as another tournament ?

so this is what I want:

```
<tournaments>

    <tournament>
        <name>a</name>
    </tournament>

    <tournament>
        <name>b</name>
    </tournament>

    <tournament>
        <name>c</name>
    </tournament>

    <tournament>
        <name>d</name>
    </tournament>

</tournaments>
```

Comment: Which xml parser are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Get [Node](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) to add from first [Document](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html);
2. Adopt [Node](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) (see [Document.adopt(Node)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#adoptNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29)) from first [Document](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) to the second [Document](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html);
3. Appent adopted [Node](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) as a child to second [Document](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) structure (see [Node.appendChild(Node)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29).

Update.
Code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document tournament = builder.parse(new File("b.xml"));
Document tournaments = builder.parse(new File("a.xml"));

Node tournamentElement = tournament.getFirstChild();
Node ndetournament = tournaments.getDocumentElement();
Node firstDocImportedNode = tournaments.adoptNode(tournamentElement);
ndetournament.appendChild(firstDocImportedNode);

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(tournaments), new StreamResult(System.out));
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<tournaments>
    <tournament>
        <name>a</name>
    </tournament>

    <tournament>
        <name>b</name>
    </tournament>

    <tournament>
        <name>c</name>
    </tournament>
<tournament>
    <name>d</name>
</tournament>
</tournaments>
```

Comment: I try this but with no succces:        Document tournament = builder.parse(new File("b.xml"));
        Document tournaments = builder.parse(new File("a.xml"));

        Element tournamentElement = (Element) tournament.getFirstChild();
        Element ndetournament = (Element) tournaments.getElementsByTagName("turnaje").item(0);
        Node firstDocImportedNode = tournaments.adoptNode(tournamentElement);
        ndetournament.appendChild(firstDocImportedNode);

Comment: ok thx this work. I didnt have to write changed xml to file With transformerFactory now it is OK

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
import java.io.StringBufferInputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class Tournament {

  private static final String tournamentData =
    "  <tournaments>" +
    "    <tournament>" +
    "        <name>a</name>" +
    "    </tournament>" +
    "    <tournament>" +
    "        <name>b</name>" +
    "    </tournament>" +
    "    <tournament>" +
    "        <name>c</name>" +
    "    </tournament>" +
    "</tournaments>";


  private static final String tournamentB =
    "    <tournament>" +
    "        <name>d</name>" +
    "    </tournament>";

  private static DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Document currentTournaments = getCurrentTournaments();
      Element tournament =  getNewTournament();
      Element ndetournament = (Element) currentTournaments.getElementsByTagName("tournaments").item(0);
      Node firstDocImportedNode = currentTournaments.importNode(tournament, true);
      ndetournament.appendChild(firstDocImportedNode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static Document getCurrentTournaments() throws Exception{
    DocumentBuilder builder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document docTournament = builder.parse(new StringBufferInputStream(tournamentData));
    return docTournament;
  }

  private static Element getNewTournament() throws Exception{
    DocumentBuilder builder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document newTournament = builder.parse(new StringBufferInputStream(tournamentData));
    Element tournament = newTournament.getDocumentElement();
    return tournament;
  }
}
```

You can ammend the getXXXX() functons suite your own code

Comment: nope I try this but with no success:          Document tournament = builder.parse(new File("b.xml"));
        Document tournaments = builder.parse(new File("a.xml"));

        Element tournamentElement = (Element) tournament.getFirstChild();
        Element ndetournament = (Element) tournaments.getElementsByTagName("turnaje").item(0);
        Node firstDocImportedNode = tournaments.importNode(tournamentElement,true);
        ndetournament.appendChild(firstDocImportedNode);

Comment: Where is "b.xml" I've retested using new File("c:\\a.xml") and it seems to work.